# Engineering notation algorithm, i.e. 1000 -> 1k, 0.001 -> 1m

Tags: algorithms, computer-science

I had to come up with a simple algorithm on a low powered embedded system, because dividing numbers by 1000s to get the wanted digits (first three basically) caused a loss in precision in the floating point operations. 10 million became 9.8M for example.

Here is my basic algorithm to get 1.00k from 1000:

- Take first 3 digits

  - 100
- Find magnitude by division, and subtract from integer length (digits)

  - 4 - 3 = 1
- Divide by appropriate power of 10:

  - 100 / 10^(3-1) = 1.00, and with magnitude known (3=k), get 1.00k.

An issue is I want to do this for numbers below 1 as well.

The first thought was inverse would work, because 1/1000 = 0.001 (k->m) but I seem to have been mistaken as the magnitude could be different on the inverted number from the non-inverse.

Is there a clever algorithm to do this?

My current code (if it needs explanation, ask) to deal with the above was this:

```
for (;value >= 1000*1000; value /= 1000) //until <condition>; do <condition>
    magnitude+=3;
if (value >= 1000)
    magnitude+=3;
    diff = digitcount(value) - magnitude;
    return firstthree(value) / 10^(3-diff);
```

I tried a for loop with `value < 1; value *= 1000` but the result was something like `100m 10m 1000u 100u 10u 1000n` (relying on inverse to get magnitude), or `0.1u, 0.01u, 0.001u` (firstthree() fails here ovviously) which is not the autoranging I am looking for of course.

I expect maybe if magnitude below 1 can be found, I can then multiply by thousands until I have a number above 1?

Comment: The arithmetic in that system is very strange. Getting the first three digits intact is the most important part. Yor code confuses me, your *magnitude* variable is acumulative, but your *value* variable gets constantly decreased.Not to risk precision, I would just read the specs  and do a hardcoded, bitwise conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Look up *scaled arithmetic*. This was popular in [FORTH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forth_%28programming_language%29) (a lightweight language that was popular in underpowered embedded systems, with integer arithmetic only).